# Excel-VB for Copying a current line to a separate worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet at work that was working up until recently. The code is listed below. It is designed to copy a line from the main worksheet to a separate worksheet based on a value in a certain column that corresponds with the matching worksheet.

It was working fine up until last week and I am not sure what is wrong with it. Was hoping that others could take a peek.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdCopyLine_Click()
Dim NextNum As String
Dim SheetName As String
Dim X As Integer

On Error GoTo ErrorOut
'    Range("A7").Select
'    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
SheetName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 42)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets(SheetName).Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A7").Select

For X = 0 To 500
    If ActiveCell.Offset(X, 0) = "" Then
        If Right(ActiveCell, 1) = "." Then NextNum = NextNum & "."
        ActiveCell.Offset(X, 0).Activate
        If NextNum = "" Then NextNum = 1
        Exit For
    End If
    NextNum = ActiveCell.Offset(X, 0) + 1
Next

ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0) = NextNum
Application.CutCopyMode = False
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub

ErrorOut:
Select Case Err.Number
    Case 9
        MsgBox "No sheet found for this Class ID", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, 
"Check Data Entry"
        Sheets("Overall Results").Activate
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Unknown error " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, 
vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Check Data Entry"
End Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Comment: Upon execution, I am getting "Unknown Error 1004 - Microsoft Excel cannot paste the data".

Comment: Do you have any merged cells or odd formatting in the source sheet?

Comment: Nope. All of the cells in the source sheet are plain, non-formatted cells.

Comment: Two suggestions, then... verify the input/output.  Having sheet names with extra spaces at the end is a pretty common issue; try and ensure that your code avoids select/activate, as to prevent issues with pulling **correct* data.